# Gnu Makefile - Handling dependencies

Tags: c++, unix, makefile, sed, gnu

What approach do C++ programmers on Unix platform use to create and manage Makefiles?

I was using hand made Makefiles for my projects but they don't handle header file changes and other dependencies. I googled around and found a good solution [here](http://make.paulandlesley.org/autodep.html).

But I ran into a problem here in the sed command -

```
    sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/^[^:]*: *//' -e 's/ *\\$$//' \
        -e '/^$$/ d' -e 's/$$/ :/' < $*.d >> $*.P; \
```

The problem is with the 3rd expression "-e 's/ *\$$//'.
It doesn't work. Its supposed to remove trailing backslashes. I understand that there has to be double dollar there since this is part of a Makefile. Can someone tell me what wrong here?

Here's the complete Makefile -

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-g -Wall
LIBS=-lpthread

OBJS=file1.o file2.o
TARGET=testProg

$(TARGET) : $(OBJS)
        $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

%.o : %.cpp
        $(CC) -MMD -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
        @cp $*.d $*.P; \
            sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/^[^:]*: *//' -e 's/ *\\$$//' \
                -e '/^$$/ d' -e 's/$$/ :/' < $*.d >> $*.P; \
            rm -f $*.d

-include $(OBJS:%.o=%.P)

clean :
        rm -f $(TARGET) $(OBJS)

all : $(TARGET)
```

Apart from the solution to this problem, I would also like some tips/pointers to my 1st question.

Comment: Hm, I threw a sed call with that third expression in a Makefile and it removed trailing backslashes. More information?

Comment: Jefromi, Updated - Added the complete Makefile

Comment: Wait a second, what Make are you using?

Comment: I am using GNU Make 3.81

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. I use [that approach](http://make.paulandlesley.org/autodep.html) too and can't praise it highly enough. And I write my makefiles by hand and reuse them a lot on new projects.

   .The expression "s/ *\\$//" will work outside the context of Make. Within a makefile it doesn't work because Make tries to interpret "$/" before handing the result to the shell. So you must use "s/ *\\$$//" (note the extra $) within the makefile, but this won't work *outside* the context of Make (so testing it is a slight pain).

**EDIT:**

I've tried your makefile, and that sed statement seems to remove trailing backslashes just fine. Try something simpler, like this:

```
backslash:
    @echo " \\" > $@

test: backslash
    @echo without sed:
    @cat backslash
    @echo with sed:
    @sed -e 's/ *\\$$//' < backslash
```

**EDIT:**
All right, now I'm hooked. Could you try these experiments and tell us the results?

```
Change the last character to 'z'      :  s/.$/z/
Change a trailing backslash to 'z'    :  s/\\$/z/
Change a trailing backslash to 'z'    :  sm\\$mzm
Delete a trailing backslash           :  s/\\$//
Delete spaces and a trailing backslash:  s/ *\\$//
Try all of these inside and outside of Make, with '$' and '$$'.
```

Comment: Use GCC's header dependancy generator switch instead.  Visual Studio has one as well.  That way you only depend on the headers that are actually included.

Comment: Thanks Beta, I have figured out my problem. Sorry it was my mistake.  That sed expression is working as it should (it's removing trailing backslashes). For some reason I thought that after removing trailing backslashes, other expressions in that command will append the lines and add a colon at the end. Colons are added at the end but lines are not appended, which is not necessary.

Answer (score 25):

gcc/g++ can generate dependencies for you with the `-M` family of options.
The following works by specifying how to generate `.depends` files given a source file.  By doing `-include $(DEPS)` $(DEPS) is recognized as a target and will be built/rebuilt when the source files change.

```
CXX      = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -O3
LDFLAGS  =

TARGET = testcpp
SRCS   = main.cc x.cc foo.cc
OBJS   = $(SRCS:.cc=.o)
DEPS   = $(SRCS:.cc=.depends)


.PHONY: clean all

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(TARGET)

.cc.o:
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

%.depends: %.cc
        $(CXX) -M $(CXXFLAGS) $< > $@

clean:
        rm -f $(OBJS) $(DEPS) $(TARGET)

-include $(DEPS)
```

Answer (score 3):

In a make file anything you list on the dependency line is a dependency header files or other files included.

[BSD tutorial on make](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/developers-handbook/tools-make.html)  Note: you can auto generate header dependency info with the -MM switch of GCC.

Answer (score 2):

I must be missing something. Why doesn't generating dependency files work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use CMake, even though it's not strictly the solution to your problem.

It's a project description language that'll generate your Makefiles, Visual Studio Project, Eclipse Project, KDevelop, etc for you.  All the dependencies are done for you:

CMakeLists.txt

```
add_executable(my_exe file1.c file2.c)
target_link_libraries(my_exe my_library)
add_subdirectory(lib)
```

In lib/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(my_library file3.c file4.c)
```

This creates a my_exe from file1.c file2.c linked against my_library.  I find this much simpler.  It also has things like package discovery:

```
find_package(Qt4)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [makedepend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makedepend) utility is installed on many systems and can be quite useful for generating dependency information.

Here is an example Makefile that uses the `include` directive (plus a little Perl magic) to incorporate the output from makedepend:

```
# the name of the executable that we'll build
TARGET = foo_prog
# our .cc source files
SRCS = foo.cc main.cc

# the .o versions of our source files
OBJS := $(patsubst %.cc, %.o, $(filter %.cc, $(SRCS)))
# some flags for compiling
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -Werror

# In order to build $(TARGET), we first build each of the $(OBJS).
# Then we use the given command to link those $(OBJS) into our
# $(TARGET) executable.  $^ is a shortcut for $(OBJS).  $@ is a
# shortcut for $(TARGET).
#
# The default compile rule will compile each of the $(OBJS) for us.
$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@

# Use "make clean" to remove all of the support files.
clean:
        rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET) Makefile.depend *~

# This automatically uses the 'makedepend' utility to add any
# dependencies that our source files have, namely .h files.  This way,
# if the .h files change, the code will be re-compiled.
include Makefile.depend
Makefile.depend: $(SRCS)
        makedepend -f- -Y $(SRCS) 2> /dev/null | \
        perl -p -e "s/(^.*?:)/Makefile.depend \1/" > Makefile.depend
```

If both `foo.cc` and `main.cc` depend on `foo.h`, then the contents of `Makefile.depend` would be:

```
Makefile.depend foo.o: foo.h
Makefile.depend main.o: foo.h
```

The end result is that the dependency information from `makedepend` is injected into the Makefile as a series of rules.  It's similar to [the approach of using a `.d` file for each `.cc` file](http://theory.uwinnipeg.ca/localfiles/infofiles/make/make_43.html#SEC42), but keeps the dependency information in one file instead of scattered all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

In Mozilla's build system, we use GCC's -MD switch to generate the dependency files:
http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/configure.in#7134
and then we use a script called mddepend.pl to check for removed header files, such that
removing a header simply causes a rebuild, not an error:
http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/config/rules.mk#2066
http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/build/unix/mddepend.pl

That script generates an .all.pp file containing all the dependencies, with extra `foo.o: FORCE` dependencies stuck in for missing header files. We then simply -include the .all.pp file in rules.mk right below there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [qmake](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qmake-manual.html) to generate Makefiles for a project even if that project is not using Qt.

Answer (score 0):

I use BSD make (pmake?) which does lot of work for me (my lang is C, but I think no difference here). This is my common 'local.prog.mk', I never change it:

```
.PHONY: tags .depend

# .depend depends only on $(SRCS) in bsd.dep.mk, so we can't track changes of
# header's own dependencies properly. so .depend is .PHONY target here.

CSTD    ?=c99
WARNS   ?=9
.if !empty(PC_LIST)
PC_CF   !=pkg-config --cflags $(PC_LIST)
PC_LD   !=pkg-config --libs   $(PC_LIST)
.endif
CFLAGS  +=$(PC_CF) -fgnu89-inline
.if !defined(NO_DEBUG)
CFLAGS  +=-O0 -ggdb3
.endif
LDFLAGS +=$(PC_LD)
CTAGS   =exctags

NO_MAN=
NO_OBJ=
CLEANFILES+=$(PROG).core

.include <bsd.prog.mk>
$(PROG): $(SUBDIR)
build: clean cleandepend depend all
run: $(PROG)
    ./$(PROG)
```

Note 'bsd.prog.mk' inclusion -- this handles all, build, depend, clean targets. Project-specific `BSDmakefile`s are simple:

```
.SILENT:

PROG    =hello
SRCS    =hello.c world.c
PC_LIST =gtk+-2.0 gnet-2.0

.include "../local.prog.mk"

proto:
    cproto -siv `pkg-config --cflags $(PC_LIST)` $(SRCS) > prototypes
CLEANFILES+=prototypes
```

I just make depend every time I insert/remove any #include directives.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the sed scripts, use gcc's -MT option to modify the target of the generated dependency rules.  [This blog post](http://blog.hashpling.org/building-code-part-ii-dependency-generation/) has more info.

Answer (score 0):

With a more modern version of GCC, you can add the -MP flag to have GCC generate empty rules for the headers itself.

Answer (score 0):

I top tip that I have found useful when building dependency files is to include the dependency file as a target in the generated rule:

```
file.d file.o : file.c header.h header2.h ...
```

Thus `make` will regenerate the dependencies if the source or any of the headers change.  Including phony targets for the headers (GCC `-MP`) should then allow stable builds when headers are removed - the absense of required header remains a compilation error, not a make dependency error.

Assuming that dependency files are generated into the same directory as the object files, the following should work for GCC on Unix:

```
-include $(OBJ:.o=.d)

$(OBJDIR)/%d : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
        mkdir -p $(@D)
        echo -n "$@ " > $@.tmp
        $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -MM -MP -MT $(@:.d=.o) $< >> $@.tmp
        mv $@.tmp $@
```

*(from memory)*